# Stop click event from propagating on popover target

Tags: reactjs, popover, blueprintjs

I am trying to disable popover open on checkbox change, placed inside the popover target. I've tried stopping `onChange` and `onClick` events on checkbox but it doesn't work as intended.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the relevant code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qm7vqmn69):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, Checkbox, Menu, MenuItem, Popover } from "@blueprintjs/core";

import "./styles.css";
import "@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
import "@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";

function Dropdown() {
  return (
    <Menu>
      <MenuItem text="Item 1" />
      <MenuItem text="Item 2" />
    </Menu>
  );
}

function MyCheckbox() {
  return (
    <Checkbox
      onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Popover content={<Dropdown />}>
        <Button text={<MyCheckbox />} rightIcon="caret-down" />
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 9):

Wrap your checkbox in another container, and prevent that from propagating up the chain:

```
function MyCheckbox() {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}
    >
      <Checkbox />
    </div>
  );
}
```

See an updated sandbox [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://codesandbox.io/s/q367k7ozmj).

Comment: wow! It did cross my mind and I thought what difference it would make and didn't even try...